# JMeter: how configure thread group with 1 user and 6 threads in parallel

Tags: jmeter

I try to find out how I can configure JMeter so that I can start a Test with 1 user and starting 6 threads in parallel, and if the first thread is finished the next thread will be started so that I have always 6 parallel threads running.

I created test plan with 1 thread group and 10 HTTP requests and when I start the test all requests will be run in sequential order.
Is there a way in JMeter to create a test plan to satisfy my requirement?

[image]

Comment: You want two opposite things "parallel" Vs "if the first thread is finished the next thread will be started"

Comment: I will have a bundle of json queries which should run with 6 threads in parallel. The runtime of these queries are different, and will be finished on different time. So when the first thread is finished the test should start the next query if not already 6 threads are running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 6 threads running in parallel you need to define 6 virtual users in the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). Each virtual user will be executing samplers upside down. When there will be no more samplers to execute or loops to iterate the thread will shut down.

If you want to execute a sampler (or samplers) at the same moment with 6 threads take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)

As an alternative you can consider using [Concurrency Thread Group](http://www.jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://www.jmeter-plugins.org/) project.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How can I define a virtual user in the Thread Group?